# Write to stdin which asks for password

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-12.04, openldap

I am working on a bash script to configure openldap and add ldif script with users and groups.

How can I write the password from the bash script ?

This is the script I run when it asks for password:

```
ldapadd -h localhost -D "cn=admin,dc=sysadmin1,dc=hioa,dc=no" -W -x -f /etc/ldap/base.ldif
```

EDIT:

I tried this and created a passwd.txt file with the password:

```
ldapadd -h localhost -D "cn=admin,dc=sysadmin1,dc=hioa,dc=no" -W -x -y'passwd.txt' -f /etc/ldap/base.ldif
```

But gets this error:

```
Warning: Password file passwd.txt is publicly readable/writeable
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

[image]

Comment: Consider using `sudo` or `super` (to run your script); perhaps use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man ldapadd.

```
-W
Prompt for simple authentication. This is used instead of specifying the password on the command line.

-w passwd
Use passwd as the password for simple authentication.
-y passwdfile
Use complete contents of passwdfile as the password for simple authentication.
```

So seems you are looking for option of `-w` or `-y`, not `-W`

Comment: I see! I changed it from -W to -w. Is it just to create a file password.txt and write the password inside it and in the command write -y=/etc/ldap/password.txt ?

Comment: Or do I have to spesify the password in the base.ldif file? But how ?

Comment: you need give the password directly, such as : `-w abc123`, abc123 is the password.

Answer (score 0):

There're two possibilities:

1. `ldapadd` reads the password from the standard input.
2. `ldapadd` reads the password directly from the current TTY.

In the first case it's enough to use something like this `echo 'MySecretPassword' | ldapadd -h localhost -D "cn=admin,dc=sysadmin1,dc=hioa,dc=no" -W -x -f /etc/ldap/base.ldif`. The second one is more complicated because you need a tool like [expect](http://oreilly.com/catalog/expect/chapter/ch03.html). Check if the simple redirection works first.

Comment: The simple redirection didn't work: https://www.dropbox.com/s/slurbt7domc4bmc/noworks.png